# WAR Does not start on tomcat5 on RedHat Enterprise server

Tags: linux, tomcat5.5

I have compiled and created .WAR file of my java code. then i started tomcat on my RedHat Server
http://www.mydomain.com:8080/
and went to admin manager and browse the .WAR file and uploaded.
The problem is that the .WAR file is uploaded successfully. but it does not starts in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing tomcat5 to tomcat7 and replacing open-jdk to sun-jdk probblem was resolved.